# replace a word with contents of a txt file containing multiple lines of strings

Tags: sed, awk

Hi I am having problem using awk,I got two files info.txt and final.txt.
info.txt has a unique no and final.txt has name address pass phone email second name address pass phone email.

I want to replace a word "pass" occured in final.txt with the content of info.txt
right now i am using this.

```
awk -v f="info" 'BEGIN {while (getline < f) txt=txt $0 "\n"} /pass/ {sub("pass", txt)}   1' final.txt.tmp > final.txt.tmp
```

Right now what it does whenever word "pass" occur in a line it relace the whole line with the content i just want to replace the word.

Thanks

Comment: Pleas post example and how you like the output.

Comment: It looks like you're messing up the file names: info vs. info.txt and final.txt.tmp (as input file) vs final.txt. With corrected file names it works. Also, it sounds like you want gsub, not sub.

Comment: Thanks I'll explain my question again my first file info.txt (containing a unique no) and other final.txt (containing multiple lines where some words need to be replaced with the unique no in info.txt).     Example  info.txt has 123 and final.txt has http://localhost?u=pass:p=pass , i need "pass" replace to be with the contents of file "info.txt"

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/\\n/g;s|.*|s/pass/&/g|' info.txt | sed -f - final.txt
```

This generates a sed script from the `info.txt` which is then run against the `final.txt`

Comment: didnt work sed: unterminated {
sed: can't open '-': No such file or directory

Comment: That what exacly i am looking  my first file info.txt (containing a unique no) and other final.txt (containing multiple lines where some words need to be replaced with the unique no in info.txt). Example info.txt has 123 and final.txt has localhost?u=pass:p=pass , i need "pass" replace to be with the contents of file "info.txt"